# Filter rows from a grouped data frame based on string columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, data-manipulation

I have a data frame grouped by multiple columns but in this example it would be grouped only by `Year`.

```
   Year Animal1  Animal2
0  2002    Dog   Mouse,Lion
1  2002  Mouse            
2  2002   Lion            
3  2002   Duck            
4  2010    Dog   Cat
5  2010    Cat            
6  2010   Lion            
7  2010  Mouse
```

I would like for each group, from the rows where `Animal2` is empty to filter out the rows where `Animal2` does not appear in the column `Animal1`.

The expected output would be:

```
  Year Animal1   Animal2
0  2002    Dog   Mouse,Lion
1  2002  Mouse            
2  2002   Lion                   
3  2010    Dog   Cat
4  2010    Cat
```

Rows 0 & 3 stayed since `Animal2` is not empty.

Rows 1 & 2 stayed since Mouse & Lion are in `Animal2` for the first group.

Row 4 stayed since cat appear in `Animal2` for the second group

**EDIT: I get an error for a similar input data frame**

```
  Year Animal1   Animal2
0  2002    Dog   Mouse
1  2002  Mouse            
2  2002   Lion                   
3  2010    Dog   
4  2010    Cat
```

The expected output would be:

```
  Year Animal1   Animal2
0  2002    Dog   Mouse
1  2002  Mouse
```

The error is triggered in the `.apply(lambda g: g.isin(sets[g.name]))` part of the code.

```
  if not any(isinstance(k, slice) for k in key):
    
                if len(key) == self.nlevels and self.is_unique:
                    # Complete key in unique index -> standard get_loc
                    try:
                        return (self._engine.get_loc(key), None)
                    except KeyError as err:
                       raise KeyError(key) from err
                         KeyError: (2010, 'Dog')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use masks and regexes:

```
# non empty Animal2
m1 = df['Animal2'].notna()

# make patterns with those Animals2 per Year
patterns = df[m1].groupby('Year')['Animal2'].agg('|'.join).str.replace(',', '|')

# for each Year select with the matching regex
m2 = (df.groupby('Year', group_keys=False)['Animal1']
        .apply(lambda g: g.str.fullmatch(patterns[g.name]))
     )

out = df.loc[m1|m2]
```

Or sets:

```
m1 = df['Animal2'].notna()

sets = (df.loc[m1, 'Animal2'].str.split(',')
          .groupby(df['Year'])
          .agg(lambda x: set().union(*x))
       )

m2 = (df.groupby('Year', group_keys=False)['Animal1']
        .apply(lambda g: g.isin(sets[g.name]))
     )

out = df.loc[m1|m2]
```

Output:

```
   Year Animal1     Animal2
0  2002     Dog  Mouse,Lion
1  2002   Mouse        None
2  2002    Lion        None
4  2010     Dog         Cat
5  2010     Cat        None
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, thank you for your answer :) it's working. Can you please explain to me what this part is doing: .agg('|'.join).str.replace(',', '|')

Comment: This is to join the strings per group and to replace the commas by `|` to craft a regex (`Mouse|Lion` for example), which will be used to match the names

Comment: Hi @mozway, I have an error if there's row which does not belong to any group. Could you please help me to fix it. I will add an edit to the description.

Comment: @thephoenix yes, please add an edit

Comment: Hi @mozway, sorry for the late reply. I included the edit. Could you please take a look and let me know. your help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using list comprehension

```
(df.loc[
    [a1 in a2 for a1,a2 in zip(df['Animal1'],df['Year'].map(df['Animal2'].str.split(',').groupby(df['Year']).sum()))] | 
    df['Animal2'].notna()]
    )
```

or

```
d = df['Animal2'].str.split(',').groupby(df['Year']).sum()

(df.loc[df.groupby('Year')['Animal1'].transform(lambda x: x.isin(d.loc[x.name])) | 
df['Animal2'].notna()]
)
```

Output:

```
   Year Animal1     Animal2
0  2002     Dog  Mouse,Lion
1  2002   Mouse        None
2  2002    Lion        None
4  2010     Dog         Cat
5  2010     Cat        None
```

Comment: the second solution is not really working for me. I get an error for d when I try to groupby three columns instead of groupby(df["Year"]). Am I missing something here ? @rhug123